# error: no matching function for call to 'UdpContext::listen(const ip_addr_t&, int&)' if(!_udp_ota->listen(*IP_ADDR_ANY, _port))

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266, ota

Getting this error when tried to upload code on Es08266 12e. The error was caused due to ArduinoOTA.

> error: no matching function for call to 'UdpContext::listen(const ip_addr_t&, int&)'
>      if(!_udp_ota->listen(*IP_ADDR_ANY, _port))
>
> note: bool UdpContext::listen(const ip_addr_t*, uint16_t)
>        bool listen(CONST ip_addr_t* addr, uint16_t port)

the code was from sample ArduinoOTA example

Comment: Found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution using a simple fix in UdpContext.h library.

As I am Linux guy follow me to find file:
Path should be : /home//.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.0/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/include/UdpContext.h

> Refer this [link](https://github.com/akashpbhardwaj/arduinoOTA/blob/master/UdpContext.h)

Now edit this file: simply replace all the code with my code which is in link

Save the code and try to restart Arduino IDE and problem will be solved.